# Total Number of Records per Week

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, generate-series

I have a Postgres 9.1 database. I am trying to generate the number of records per week (for a given date range) and compare it to the previous year.

I have the following code used to generate the series:

```
select generate_series('2013-01-01', '2013-01-31', '7 day'::interval) as series
```

However, I am not sure how to join the counted records to the dates generated.

So, using the following records as an example:

```
Pt_ID      exam_date
======     =========
1          2012-01-02
2          2012-01-02
3          2012-01-08
4          2012-01-08
1          2013-01-02
2          2013-01-02
3          2013-01-03
4          2013-01-04
1          2013-01-08
2          2013-01-10
3          2013-01-15
4          2013-01-24
```

I wanted to have the records return as:

```
  series        thisyr      lastyr
===========     =====       =====
2013-01-01        4           2
2013-01-08        3           2
2013-01-15        1           0
2013-01-22        1           0
2013-01-29        0           0
```

Not sure how to reference the date range in the subsearch. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: How exactly were you planning to treat the week from '2012-12-30' to '2013-01-05'? Weeks cross the borders between years, so your idea is flawed by design: Every year, weeks would start with a different day and the last week is truncated more or less. [I suggest to use ISO weeks instead](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC): `By definition (ISO 8601), weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year.` Could that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a`cross join`should work, I'm just going to paste the markdown output from SQL Fiddle below. It would seem that your sample output is incorrect for series 2013-01-08: the thisyr should be 2, not 3. This might not be the best way to do this though, my Postgresql knowledge leaves a lot to be desired.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6e1da/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.2.4 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("Pt_ID" varchar(6), "exam_date" date);

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("Pt_ID", "exam_date")
VALUES
    ('1', '2012-01-02'),('2', '2012-01-02'),
    ('3', '2012-01-08'),('4', '2012-01-08'),
    ('1', '2013-01-02'),('2', '2013-01-02'),
    ('3', '2013-01-03'),('4', '2013-01-04'),
    ('1', '2013-01-08'),('2', '2013-01-10'),
    ('3', '2013-01-15'),('4', '2013-01-24');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
  series, 
  sum (
    case 
      when exam_date 
        between series and series + '6 day'::interval
      then 1 
      else 0 
    end
  ) as thisyr,
  sum (
    case 
      when exam_date + '1 year'::interval 
        between series and series + '6 day'::interval
      then 1 else 0 
    end
  ) as lastyr

from table1
cross join generate_series('2013-01-01', '2013-01-31', '7 day'::interval) as series
group by series
order by series
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6e1da/1/0)**:

```
|                         SERIES | THISYR | LASTYR |
|--------------------------------|--------|--------|
| January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      4 |      2 |
| January, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |      2 |
| January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |      0 |
| January, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      1 |      0 |
| January, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      0 |      0 |
```

Comment: Thank you. The code does work well. I would like to understand something, though - when sum for lastyr, why is exam_date + '1 year' produce the previous year. I am a little confused about that.

Comment: Oh, as the series is for the current year and you want to count occurrences in the previous year it seemed easiest to just add a year to the date, which would make the dates one year back fall into the series. An alternative would have been to do something like `when exam_date between series - '1 year'::interval and series + '6 day -1 year'::interval`I guess. Not sure how to write the interval in that case though.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I've got it. What would you suggest to include dates from another table (ie. to have two more columns with this_year and last_year from my_date in Table2). I am having a little trouble with it.

Comment: Not sure, you could try adding another cross join and treat it like the first table?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That's a good point, I guess it would give some odd results, however I think your comment should be directed at Kipsoft (not sure the OP will get notified of your comment too); I just showed how to connect the generated series with the dates table. Ideally I think using a calendar table might be a better choice, or something similar.

Comment: @jpw: Sorry, wanted to address kipsoft, posted under your answer by mistake. BTW, I agree `(series, thisyr)` should be `('2013-01-08', 2)` not `3`. As for the query: cross join works nicely, but performance deteriorates with big sets.

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach would be to solve this with a CROSS JOIN like demonstrated by @jpw. However, there are some hidden **problems**:

1. The **performance** of an unconditional `CROSS JOIN` deteriorates quickly with growing number of rows. The total number of rows is multiplied by the number of weeks you are testing for, before this huge derived table can be processed in the aggregation. Indexes can't help.
2. Starting weeks with January 1st leads to inconsistencies. **ISO weeks** might be an alternative. See below.

All of the following queries make heavy use of an **index on `exam_date`**. Be sure to have one.

#### Only join to relevant rows

Should be *much faster*:

```
SELECT d.day, d.thisyr
     , count(t.exam_date) AS lastyr
FROM  (
   SELECT d.day::date, (d.day - '1 year'::interval)::date AS day0  -- for 2nd join
        , count(t.exam_date) AS thisyr
   FROM   generate_series('2013-01-01'::date
                        , '2013-01-31'::date  -- last week overlaps with Feb.
                        , '7 days'::interval) d(day)  -- returns timestamp
   LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.exam_date >= d.day::date
                    AND t.exam_date <  d.day::date + 7
   GROUP  BY d.day
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.exam_date >= d.day0      -- repeat with last year
                 AND t.exam_date <  d.day0 + 7
GROUP  BY d.day, d.thisyr
ORDER  BY d.day;
```

This is with weeks starting from Jan. 1st like in your original. As commented, this produces a couple of inconsistencies: Weeks start on a different day each year and since we cut off at the end of the year, the last week of the year consists of just 1 or 2 days (leap year).

#### The same with ISO weeks

Depending on requirements, consider **ISO weeks** instead, which start on Mondays and always span 7 days. But they cross the border between years. [Per documentation on `EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> week
>
> The number of the week of the year that the day is in. By definition (ISO 8601), weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a
>   year contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first
>   Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.
>
> In the ISO definition, it is possible for early-January dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and for
>   late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year. For
>   example, `2005-01-01` is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and
>   `2006-01-01` is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while `2012-12-31` is
>   part of the first week of 2013. It's recommended to use the `isoyear`
>   field together with `week` to get consistent results.

Above query rewritten with ISO weeks:

```
SELECT w AS isoweek
     , day::text  AS thisyr_monday, thisyr_ct
     , day0::text AS lastyr_monday, count(t.exam_date) AS lastyr_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT w, day
        , date_trunc('week', '2012-01-04'::date)::date + 7 * w AS day0
        , count(t.exam_date) AS thisyr_ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT w
           , date_trunc('week', '2013-01-04'::date)::date + 7 * w AS day
      FROM   generate_series(0, 4) w
      ) d
   LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.exam_date >= d.day
                    AND t.exam_date <  d.day + 7
   GROUP  BY d.w, d.day
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.exam_date >= d.day0     -- repeat with last year
                 AND t.exam_date <  d.day0 + 7
GROUP  BY d.w, d.day, d.day0, d.thisyr_ct
ORDER  BY d.w, d.day;
```

January 4th is always in the first ISO week of the year. So this expression gets the date of Monday of the first ISO week of the given year:

```
date_trunc('week', '2012-01-04'::date)::date
```

#### Simplify with [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Since ISO weeks coincide with the week numbers returned by `EXTRACT()`, we can simplify the query. First, a short and simple form:

```
SELECT w AS isoweek
     , COALESCE(thisyr_ct, 0) AS thisyr_ct
     , COALESCE(lastyr_ct, 0) AS lastyr_ct
FROM   generate_series(1, 5) w
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM exam_date)::int AS w, count(*) AS thisyr_ct
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  EXTRACT(isoyear FROM exam_date)::int = 2013
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t13  USING (w)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM exam_date)::int AS w, count(*) AS lastyr_ct
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  EXTRACT(isoyear FROM exam_date)::int = 2012
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t12  USING (w);
```

### Optimized query

The same with more details and optimized for performance

```
WITH params AS (          -- enter parameters here, once 
   SELECT date_trunc('week', '2012-01-04'::date)::date AS last_start
        , date_trunc('week', '2013-01-04'::date)::date AS this_start
        , date_trunc('week', '2014-01-04'::date)::date AS next_start
        , 1 AS week_1
        , 5 AS week_n     -- show weeks 1 - 5
   )
SELECT w.w AS isoweek
     , p.this_start + 7 * (w - 1) AS thisyr_monday
     , COALESCE(t13.ct, 0) AS thisyr_ct
     , p.last_start + 7 * (w - 1) AS lastyr_monday
     , COALESCE(t12.ct, 0) AS lastyr_ct
FROM params p
   , generate_series(p.week_1, p.week_n) w(w)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM t.exam_date)::int AS w, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl t, params p
   WHERE  t.exam_date >= p.this_start      -- only relevant dates
   AND    t.exam_date <  p.this_start + 7 * (p.week_n - p.week_1 + 1)::int
-- AND    t.exam_date <  p.next_start      -- don't cross over into next year
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t13  USING (w)
LEFT   JOIN (                              -- same for last year
   SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM t.exam_date)::int AS w, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   tbl t, params p
   WHERE  t.exam_date >= p.last_start
   AND    t.exam_date <  p.last_start + 7 * (p.week_n - p.week_1 + 1)::int
-- AND    t.exam_date <  p.this_start
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t12  USING (w);
```

This should be very fast with index support and can easily be adapted to intervals of choice.
The implicit `JOIN LATERAL` for `generate_series()` in the last query requires **Postgres 9.3**.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/33348/28)